# Why is this debounce function breaking "this"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I created a debounce utility function:

```
debounce (func, wait, immediate) {
  let timeout
  return function () {
    const context = this
    const args = arguments
    const later = function () {
      timeout = null
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args)
    }
    const callNow = immediate && !timeout
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait)
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args)
  }
}
```

Which I use like this:

```
updateField: utils.debounce((event, fieldName, schema) => {
  const value = event.target.value
  this.$emit('updateField', fieldName, value, schema)
  validateFields(this)
}, 500),
```

The debounce function works. However I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.$emit is not a function
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `updateField` is a Vue method, since this is tagged with Vue, it's because you are using an arrow function.

Change it to  a regular function.

```
updateField: utils.debounce(function(event, fieldName, schema){
  const value = event.target.value
  this.$emit('updateField', fieldName, value, schema)
  validateFields(this)
}, 500)
```

You shouldn't define Vue methods with arrow functions. The reason being Vue binds the methods to the Vue and arrow functions cannot be bound (you cannot change their `this`).